# WPF Style Triggers: can I apply the one style for a variety of Properties?

Tags: wpf, listbox, triggers, styles, listboxitem

It seems like there has to be a way to do this:

I am applying an ItemContainerStyle in my Listbox, based on two property triggers.  As you can see, I'm using the exact same set of trigger enter/exit actions, simply applied on two different properties.  Is there something equivalent to a <Trigger Property="prop1" OR Property="prop2"> ??? (Obviously wouldn't look like that, but that probably gets the point across.)

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                        To="50" Duration="0:0:.3"></DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                              To="25" Duration="0:0:.3" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>


            </Style.Triggers>


   </Style>
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                        To="50" Duration="0:0:.3"></DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                              To="25" Duration="0:0:.3" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>


            </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried any of the following (extracted from Adam Nathan's book: *Windows Presentation Foundation Unleashed*):

- Multiple triggers applied to the same element (to get a logical OR).
- Multiple properties evaluated for the same trigger (to get a logical AND).

### Logical OR

Since Style.Triggers can contain multiple triggers, you can create more than one with the exact same Setters to express a logical OR relationship.

For example:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        ...
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
        ....
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

This means, "if **IsMouseOver** is true *or* if **IsKeyboardFocusWithin** is true, apply the action.

### Logical AND

To express a logical AND relationship, you can use a variation of **Trigger** called **MultiTrigger**, or a variation of **DataTrigger** called **MultiDataTrigger**. Both triggers have a collection of **Conditions** that contain the information you would normally put directly inside a Trigger or DataTrigger.

For example:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
        <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True"/>
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    </MultiTrigger>
        <Setter ...>
        <Setter ...>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.   My problem is that I was looking to express a logical AND relationship without Specifying the Setters again.  In your example above, I have to copy the same group of set of setters for each trigger in the trigger collection.  This becomes tedious if I want to make changes to the setter values later on...   The MultiTrigger is helpful though, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can put the Storyboards into resources and just reference them in the triggers. It's not exactly what you want, but it allows you to define your animations in one central place (rather than having to copy & paste them).

```
<Style TargetType="...">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="MyGetFocusAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                             To="50" Duration="0:0:.3" />
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="MyLoseFocusAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                             To="25" Duration="0:0:.3" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MyGetFocusAnimation}" />
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MyLoseFocusAnimation}" />
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MyGetFocusAnimation}" />
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MyLoseFocusAnimation}" />
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```