# Is there anyway of consolidating similar data bindings and/or triggers in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a user control that hosts other controls. The way I implemented this is via data templates that define the control that should be associated with a specific view-model. These view-models have similar properties and interaction triggers. Please see XAML snippet below.

The problem with this approach is that I would have to copy-paste the data bindings if I want to support a new view-model. Is there any way of consolidating all similar data bindings and/or triggers into one template? I don't want to type/copy-paste the same data binding definitions into each control. (Yes, I know, I'm that lazy.)

```
<UserControl.Resources>   
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SomeViewModel1}">
        <TextBlock Canvas.Left="{Binding Left}"
                   Canvas.Top="{Binding Top}"
                   RenderTransform="{Binding Transform}"
                   Height="{Binding Height}"
                   Width="{Binding Width}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MouseEnterCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MouseLeaveCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SomeViewModel2}">
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="{Binding Left}"
                   Canvas.Top="{Binding Top}"
                   RenderTransform="{Binding Transform}"
                   Height="{Binding Height}"
                   Width="{Binding Width}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MouseEnterCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MouseLeaveCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Rectangle>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SomeViewModel3}">
        <Button Canvas.Left="{Binding Left}"
                Canvas.Top="{Binding Top}"
                RenderTransform="{Binding Transform}"
                Height="{Binding Height}"
                Width="{Binding Width}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MouseEnterCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MouseLeaveCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SomeViewModel4}">
       <!-- Do not want copy-paste code here... -->
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Please check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665267/datatemplate-datatypecollectionentity

Comment: Please check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665267/datatemplate-datatypecollectionentity

Comment: I think that's for a different problem altogether. That's for a list of items. My problem is dealing with objects of similar traits.

Comment: Hi, this fits in your case as well. You'll have those VM's whom all want to share the same template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use common style, and put both your properties and triggers (which are also properties) inside this style, look at this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439321/wpf-style-triggers-can-i-apply-the-one-style-for-a-variety-of-properties)
for more details.

Comment: I think you're correct. Although I still do not know how to do this in detail, at least I now know the general direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about putting the triggers into a resource and associating them with your controls. Or use a custom base class for your DataTemplates.

Comment: I'm not really an expert in XAML. Do you have any code snippet available to illustrate that?